# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable or insert_new_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'newname' and 'newemail'

Tags: python, sqlite

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tried adding -def insert_new_user(newname,newemail)
but then I get:
TypeError: insert_new_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'newname' and 'newemail'

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
d = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersdata(name TEXT,reason TEXT,startDate TEXT,endDate TEXT)')
    d.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersname(name TEXT,email TEXT)')

def insert_new_user():
    newname = str(entry_new_name.get())
    newemail = str(entry_new_email.get())
    d.execute('INSERT INTO usersname(name, email) values (?,?)' (newname,newemail))
    conn.commit()


create_table()

label_new_name = Label(tab4,text="New Full Name", padx=5, pady=5)
label_new_name.grid(column=0, row=1)
new_name_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_new_name = Entry(tab4, textvariable=new_name_raw_entry, width=60)
entry_new_name.grid(row=1, column=1)

label_new_email = Label(tab4,text="New Email", padx=5,pady=5)
label_new_email.grid(column=0, row=2)
new_email_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_new_email = Entry(tab4, textvariable=new_email_raw_entry, width=60)
entry_new_email.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

I would like it to write the new name and email to the database usersname.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you may have previously named a string-object `str`, overriding the type-object. So now you're calling a string, which--as the error message suggests--isn't possible.

Comment: I checked for that issue to be sure and this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a comma after '''values (?,?)' ''' so it was looking at the whole thing as one.
I also don't need str for  '''newname = **str**(entry_new_name.get())'''